# jquery : redirect works first than .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, each

i have js function

```
function addAllToCart(){
    var have_result = false;
    jQuery("input#qty").each(function(indx, e){
      if (e.value != ''){
        //alert(indx);
        jQuery.get("/checkout/cart/add/", { product: e.name, qty: e.value }, {async: false},
             function(data){});
        have_result = true;
       }
    });

    if (have_result)
        document.location.href = "/checkout/cart/";

    return false;
}
```

it find on page all inputs with id qty, get it name and value and make ajax request to add to cart. there are many these inputs on on page, so i need to add all of them and then rediret to  "/checkout/cart/"; but only first value adds to cart and then works redirect. how can i do redirect only after making all ajax requests??

Comment: your cart items are stored in db or session or cookies on ? are you callling your side scripting language multiple times to store one cart item at  a time?

Comment: i add product by requesting the url, so i need to add all goods to cart and then redirect to cart page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the signature of [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

```
jQuery.get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

you don't call the method correctly.

Also, you should use `post` instead of `get` to add your items into session or db. `Get` does work in practice, you can get item information from query strings. but It's just wrong doing it this way. you should use `post`

Comment: it works fine. if i remove redirect, it adds all goods to cart

Comment: it's not fine. your {async:false} doesnt work. that's why it redirects before each() is completed.